# Unable to enable hotspot option in android 4.4

Tags: wifi-hotspot

The device of mine is Lenovo A5500 and I used to see tethering and hotspot option in setting but I am now unable to locate that. Actually it is I here but I don't see any option to configure and enable it. Screens are included for more information. 
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The option for WiFi hotspot should be restored after rebooting the android handset, at least it was the case for me. [image]